# EntityManager (Hibernate + MySQL) truncates the string at the White-Space while updating

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

The code is:

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerProvider.get();
String qry = "UPDATE MyTable x SET x.txt='123 321' WHERE ID=1";            
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(qry);
query.executeUpdate();
```

What I get in a database is '123' instead of '123 321'.
The varchar is 255, and it always truncates at the white-space!
If I use the normal SQL query, there is no issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That makes no sense. Are you sure the code you posted is responsible for that result?

Comment: I doubt it's connected to hibernate. Have you checked the setter method for your MyTable class? Make sure that it's not the one who truncates the string.

Comment: @vtor, yes I had, everything is OK before running the query.executeUpdate();

Comment: @f1sh, you are right, it makes no sense at all and I am stuck with it for several hours.

Comment: Neither MySql nor hibernate splits strings at whitespace. Can you debug into the hibernate code to see what happens with the values?

Comment: Have you tried using `UPDATE MyTable x SET x.txt = :text WHERE ID = :id` and then specify 2 parameters on your query, one for `text` and the other for `id` with your values?

Comment: @f1sh, unfortunately, I cannot use the debug mode with this project, If I do the query.getParameter(0).getName(), I get this error:     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(Ljava/net/URL;)Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: @DamirOlejar your ``query`` has no parameters, so calling ``getParameter(0)`` should crash anyways. But that ``NoSuchMethodError`` sounds there is something broken on the inside.

Comment: @Naros, thanks, that was part of a problem, second part was displaying a getter

Comment: @vtor, thanks, solved!

Comment: @f1sh, thanks, hibernate was an issue, and it was solved with :param syntax, the rest was a getter that did not display things properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in this case is to use:

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerProvider.get();
String qry = "UPDATE MyTable x SET x.txt=:txtParam WHERE ID=1";            
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(qry);
query.setParameter("txtParam", "123 321");

query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: What do you mean by a getter that is truncating the String?  Can you update your original question with those specific details?

Comment: I am curious though if the following SQL would work for MySQL rather than using parameterize queries, "UPDATE MyTable x SET xtxt = \"123 321\" WHERE ID=1".  You'll notice the string value is double-quoted rather than single-quoted.